# Where should I install the Workflow Manager for Sharepoint Server 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow-manager

I have the following Izone3 Architecture:
1. WFE Server (SharePoint Server 2013 is installed)
2. Application Server (SharePoint Server 2013 is installed)
3. SharePoint Database Server (SharePoint Server is not installed)
4. Server for Workflow(SharePoint Server is not installed)

I am thinking of connecting the workflow manager to my SharePoint server. I want to install it in a separate isolated server so that the workflow load does not effect any other server.

Which server should I be installing the Workflow Manager and Workflow client ?

Should I be installing Workflow Manager in Server no 4  and Workflow Client in Server 1 ?

Comment: Did you tried this link   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/governance/install-and-configure-workflow-for-sharepoint-server

Comment: What are the specifications that you used for Workflow Manager Machine?

Answer (score 2):

Workflow Client must go on all SharePoint servers in the farm. If you want a dedicated server for WFM, you can do that, or alternatively install it on your App server. Whether or not it needs a dedicated server depends on WFM usage. Light, initial usage does not require a dedicated server. You can always move it down the road.